# Change the positive negative breakpoint (default 0)

Tags: javascript, charts, visualization, recharts

I would like to create the following visual with Recharts:

[image: target visual]

Ignore the colors or the orientation, only focus on the breakpoint for a positive or a negative bar. Which in my case is 100.
Below 100 the bar goes to the left, above 100 the bar goes to the right.

I manage to make a visual like this:

[image]

The difference between both visuals is that my breakpoint for a positive / negative bar is 100, while default it is 0.

Anybody has a clue on how to get started to change the 0 breakpoint to a custom value?

Edit: Only method I can think of is subtracting my data by the custom value and then add a customContent to the axis and the labels where I add the customvalue again so it shows correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question by substracting my datapoints by 100 and and in the formatter of the label and the x-axis I added 100 again:

[image]